# javascript neo4-driver fails to return multiple variables

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I use neo4j-driver to query neo4j. This works mostly fine, but the command :

```
match (city:city)-[r:lies_in]->(country:country) return city,country
```

returns only the city. 
**The exactly same command works perfectly fine in Neo4j- Browser and returns city and country.**

This is the line from the neo4j query.log :

```
2019-04-25 07:19:21.870+0000 INFO  4 ms: bolt-session   bolt        neo4j-javascript/1.7.3      client/127.0.0.1:49824  server/127.0.0.1:7687>   - match (city:city)-[r:lies_in]->(country:country) return city,country - {} - {}
```

this is the relevant code:

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

            const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://127.0.0.1:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('', ''));
            const session = driver.session();

            console.log (command);

            session.run(
              `${command}`
            )
            .then(result => {
              session.close();
              console.log (result);
```

logged result: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only consuming the first record of the results.

See the [driver documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/cypher-values/#driver-result) for how to iterate over the rest of the records in the results stream.